# Trying To Loop Through API GET Request Vector

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm trying to loop thorugh my vector. But it seems like it just passes right through it.

As you can see I have my the API url, when I trie to manipulate the DOM by using data.title for example the browser tells me 'undefined'.

```
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', loadData); //Onload go to function loadData

let container = document.querySelector(".container")
function loadData() {


window.fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=US&apiKey=09a07c4fc0d9457696f8d3cc6b37baf5').then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
}).then(function(data) {

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]);
  }

});
}
```

Here's an exampel when I get it undefined:

```
let title = document.createElement('p');
 title.className = 'card-text';
 title.innerHTML = '<b>Title:</b> ' + data.title;
 title.appendChild(title);
```

Comment: Where do you try to use `data.title` in your snippet?  Also `data` is an array, which you should be aware of, as you're looping over it.

Comment: Please provide the context in which you are doing the second snippet, related to the first snippet.  It's unclear if you are doing that inside a callback or not.

Comment: As @Taplar already pointed out, don't forget to call the property on a single element of the array. When inside your for loop, e.g. you should get the title by `data[i].title`.

Comment: In fact, looking at how the API response behaves (btw. you should not include your API key for the public), "data" is not the array you are looking for. It would be "data.articles".